# Google Chrome Element Inspector (Developer Tools) removes HTML element in my page

Tags: html, wordpress, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using WordPress and on the admin side when I use Google Chrome v.32 Element Inspector (Developer Tools) some of the elements in my HTML seems to be removed. But when I load my page without the Developer Tools all my elements are there.

I did not have this problem with the previous version of Google Chrome.

I cannot post the code here, first because it's way to long and second I am not allowed. But maybe others have experienced the same problem and others might even have the solution.

I know it is not my JavaScript because it is not even downloaded the script elements have been removed for some reason because of the Developer Tools being open.

Basically why when I have the Developer Tools open for a page that page as some of it's elements removed and when I re-load the page without Developer Tools everything is back to normal?

Comment: Maybe post a screenshot of this happening in Chrome, not happening in Chrome, and maybe a screenshot from another browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. For some reason the emulator was open. And set like this:

[image: Emulation]

All I had to do is unchecked "Spoof user agent".